# injecting redux state into component, re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In the documentation of redux:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-dispatch-and-every-field-in-the-global-state

it says for injecting the complete state into a connected component, that this kills performance, since the component would re-render on every action.

Now I wonder, why that is. Wouldn't the default strict equal `areStatesEqual` function and also the default shallow equal `areStatePropsEqual` function catch at least the situations, where the state hasn't changed? Or is the documentation assuming, that the state probably changes on every action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`each only listen to a relevant slice of the state`

That is exactly what you want. You don't want to inject your complete state into every component, since then every time a piece of state changes, every component will re-render, event when that piece of state is not relevant to most of the components. You don't want components to listen to state that isn't relevant to them, since then they will perform useless re-renders, which is bad for performance.

In most cases, at least some piece of state will change when an action is fired, since that is the whole point of actions. To trigger state updates.

Comment: OK, so to be clear, my component would not re-render, if the state would not change, correct?

Comment: @ghost23 Yes, if an action is fired, but it doesn't result in a change of the state injected into the component, the component won't re-render.This assumes that your app is written correctly and you don't do things like create new instances in render() functions, etc. This article is quite helpful: https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f